# Issues printing a dash on Java

Tags: java

I am writing a program that simulates the translation of an alphabetic phone number into just numbers. For example: 888-get-food == 555-438-3663.

Initially, the user should enter the phone number on the following format: 888-GET-FOOD (With the dashes). When I try to check if there are dashes on the user input, it prints the dashes, but with the number 1 in front of it. Very annoying.

This is what I have so far:

```
// Ask the user to enter the phone number
System.out.println("Please enter the phone number: ");

// Save the phone number into a string
String initialPhoneNumber = input.nextLine();

// Convert user input to UPPERCASE
initialPhoneNumber = initialPhoneNumber.toUpperCase();

// This will be the phone number converted
String finalPhoneNumber = fullPhoneNumber(initialPhoneNumber);

// Print number
System.out.println(initialPhoneNumber);
System.out.println(finalPhoneNumber);

for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {

  char letter = initialPhoneNumber.charAt(i);

  if (Character.isLetter(letter)) {

    switch (letter) {
      case 'A': case 'B': case 'C': number = 2; break;
      case 'D': case 'E': case 'F': number = 3; break;
      case 'G': case 'H': case 'I': number = 4; break;
      case 'J': case 'K': case 'L': number = 5; break;
      case 'M': case 'N': case 'O': number = 6; break;
      case 'P': case 'Q': case 'R': case 'S': number = 7; break;
      case 'T': case 'U': case 'V': number = 8; break;
      case 'W': case 'X': case 'Y': case 'Z': number = 9; break;
      case '-':number='-';

    }
  }

  else if (Character.isDigit(letter)) {
    number = Character.getNumericValue(letter);
  }

  else if (initialPhoneNumber.charAt(i) == '-') {
      number = Character.getNumericValue(letter);
  }
```

and this is the output:

Please enter the phone number: 
555-GET-FOOD
555-GET-FOOD
555-1438-13663

Why does the number 1 show up in front of the dashes? How can I make it so it doesn't show up? In other words, how can I print or separate the numbers separated by dashes?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels by the same logic, almost every question is a "duplicate" of that.

Comment: Have a close look at the code after `else if (initialPhoneNumber.charAt(i) == '-') {` ....

Comment: Hint: what value do you expect `Character.getNumericValue('-')` to return?

Comment: @Michael: yes and no. Most questions should show results of debugging attempts prior to asking, if only to isolate the error, and this one doesn't.

Comment: Some feedback to how you should ask questions here (and how you might resolve your questions on your own): Make a [minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), in accordance to SO's rules. Your mistake isn't spread out in the entirety of the code, it's likely only in one specific line. Find and only post this one line, so we don't have to do this work for you. Your problem will most likely resolve itself, then, too. Expending some effort yourself instead of coming here asking us to debug your program is not forbidden.

Comment: We don't know what `letter` is, we don't know what `i` is, where don't know what `fullPhoneNumber()` does.

Comment: The code is incomplete, is the second half of your code from `fullPhoneNumber`?

Comment: So, what can you recommend to do.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is within the statement:

```
else if (initialPhoneNumber.charAt(i) == '-') {
  number = Character.getNumericValue(letter);
}
```

The method `Character.getNumericValue()` returrns `-1` if the character passed as parameter is not numeric.
Since you're passing `-`, the method returns `-1`.
That's why you get the `1` after the dash.

**UPDATE**

Supposing that the for-loop is part of your method `fullPhoneNumber`, you could resolve it as follows:

```
public String fullPhoneNumber(String initialPhoneNumber)
{
  StringBuilder result;
  result = new StringBuilder();

  for (int i = 0; i < initialPhoneNumber.length(); i++)
  {
    char letter = Character.toUpperCase(initialPhoneNumber.charAt(i));
    switch (letter)
    {
      case 'A':
      case 'B':
      case 'C':
        letter = '2';
        break;
      case 'D':
      case 'E':
      case 'F':
        letter = '3';
        break;
      case 'G':
      case 'H':
      case 'I':
        letter = '4';
        break;
      case 'J':
      case 'K':
      case 'L':
        letter = '5';
        break;
      case 'M':
      case 'N':
      case 'O':
        letter = '6';
        break;
      case 'P':
      case 'Q':
      case 'R':
      case 'S':
        letter = '7';
        break;
      case 'T':
      case 'U':
      case 'V':
        letter = '8';
        break;
      case 'W':
      case 'X':
      case 'Y':
      case 'Z':
        letter = '9';
        break;
      case '0':
      case '1':
      case '2':
      case '3':
      case '4':
      case '5':
      case '6':
      case '7':
      case '8':
      case '9':
      case '-':
        break;
      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("");
    }

    result.append(letter);

  } // for

  return (result.toString());

} // fullPhoneNumber
```

Comment: Indeed. It's just slightly confusing because minus and dash share the same symbol. 'Minus one', not 'a dash followed by a one'.

Comment: So, what can you recommend to do?